# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have upgraded my RDS amazon db instance (postgresql database ) from micro to small about an hour ago. Although it says that it is available on the amazon console, I keep getting the error `(psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out.` everytime I access the db from my app.

I am really not an expert so I don't know what could be wrong because everything was working fine before that.

when trying to access the server from my ubuntu machine with:

```
psql -h Ip -d db -U myuser
```

I get the same error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "IP" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

On the other hand, everything seems fine as well inside of PgAdmin4.

I am wondering if I just need to wait a bit longer to let things initialize. By the way, I am working on a django project, are there some settings that I need to take care off after such an upgrate? Has someone had the same problem?

here is postgres error log:

```
2020-08-07 10:00:16 UTC::@:[13371]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:00:16 UTC::@:[13371]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.132 s; sync files=1, longest=0.005 s, average=0.005 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65537 kB
2020-08-07 10:05:16 UTC::@:[13371]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:05:16 UTC::@:[13371]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.136 s; sync files=1, longest=0.005 s, average=0.005 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65537 kB
2020-08-07 10:10:16 UTC::@:[13371]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:10:16 UTC::@:[13371]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.135 s; sync files=1, longest=0.005 s, average=0.005 s; distance=65534 kB, estimate=65537 kB
2020-08-07 10:12:03 UTC::@:[13368]:LOG: received fast shutdown request
2020-08-07 10:12:03 UTC::@:[13368]:LOG: aborting any active transactions
2020-08-07 10:12:03 UTC::@:[13368]:LOG: background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 13377) exited with exit code 1
2020-08-07 10:12:03 UTC::@:[13371]:LOG: shutting down
2020-08-07 10:12:03 UTC::@:[13371]:LOG: checkpoint starting: shutdown immediate
2020-08-07 10:12:03 UTC::@:[13371]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.000 s, sync=0.007 s, total=0.037 s; sync files=1, longest=0.007 s, average=0.007 s; distance=65535 kB, estimate=65537 kB
2020-08-07 10:12:03 UTC::@:[13368]:LOG: database system is shut down
2020-08-07 10:12:06 UTC::@:[28963]:LOG: database system was shut down at 2020-08-07 10:12:03 UTC
2020-08-07 10:12:06 UTC::@:[28961]:LOG: database system is ready to accept connections
2020-08-07 10:17:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:17:07 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 3 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.881 s, sync=0.006 s, total=0.921 s; sync files=3, longest=0.006 s, average=0.002 s; distance=16 kB, estimate=16 kB
2020-08-07 10:22:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:22:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.678 s, sync=0.006 s, total=0.712 s; sync files=1, longest=0.006 s, average=0.006 s; distance=65521 kB, estimate=65521 kB
2020-08-07 10:27:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:27:07 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.693 s, sync=0.006 s, total=0.727 s; sync files=1, longest=0.006 s, average=0.006 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65536 kB
2020-08-07 10:32:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:32:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.131 s; sync files=1, longest=0.005 s, average=0.005 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65536 kB
2020-08-07 10:37:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:37:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.131 s; sync files=1, longest=0.005 s, average=0.005 s; distance=65535 kB, estimate=65536 kB
2020-08-07 10:42:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:42:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.132 s; sync files=1, longest=0.005 s, average=0.005 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65536 kB
2020-08-07 10:47:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:47:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.135 s; sync files=1, longest=0.005 s, average=0.005 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65536 kB
2020-08-07 10:52:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:52:07 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.006 s, total=0.133 s; sync files=1, longest=0.006 s, average=0.006 s; distance=65535 kB, estimate=65536 kB
2020-08-07 10:57:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint starting: time
2020-08-07 10:57:06 UTC::@:[28964]:LOG: checkpoint complete: wrote 1 buffers (0.0%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 1 recycled; write=0.101 s, sync=0.005 s, total=0.137 s; sync files=1, longest=0.005 s, average=0.005 s; distance=65536 kB, estimate=65536 kB
----------------------- END OF LOG ----------------------
```

UPDATE: I tried testing the port on the server, rebooting my RDS instance nothing works, I have also uninstalled and re installed psycopg2 and sqlalchemy.

I can connect to the db from the command line.
I tested the port with nmap, giving the following result:

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
5432/tcp filtered postgresql
```

I am still super confused and the app not working for the past 10 hours!

UPDATE:
I have just noticed that in the aws console in `database/mydb/configurations/parameters group`, it says `default.postgres11 (in-sync)`. Could that be the cause of the sudden issue after the upgrade? I don't remember saying in-sync before, I wonder how long it is going to last

Comment: are you able to connect from command line? the logs shows the issue with the client not with the DB, if pgadmin4 working then possible issue with the client, which client or library you are using in the application side?

Comment: I successfully connect to db from command line. On the client side, I am using django, to access the db I use sqlalchemy and psycodb2